# How to get the terms from WooCommerce product attribute taxonomies?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, taxonomy-terms

With the following code I populate a select dropdown item in Admin product page which I add, through a function *(in my theme's functions.php)*. For instance, I managed to get the list of all my product attributes *(taxanomy)*:

```
<?php               
    $attributes =  wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
    if($attributes) {
        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
            echo '<option value="'. $attribute->attribute_id .'">' . $attribute->attribute_label . '</option>';
        }
    }               
?>
```

Any idea how the get the term names (labels) and ids of all the terms under a specific product attribute *(taxanomy)*, for example `pa_test`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [function `get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) to get all the terms of our product attribute taxonomies as follows *(here for product attribute `pa_test` taxonomy)*:

```
$taxonomy = 'pa_test';
$terms    = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'hide_empty' => false) );

// Loop through the terms for 'pa_test' taxonomy
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_name = $term->name; // name
    $term_slug = $term->slug; // slug
    $term_id   = $term->term_id; // Id
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term ); // Link
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your quick reply. Unfortunatley it only shows 9 of 41 terms... i don't know why. Never saw anything like that...

Comment: @evavienna Updated, it should show all terms now. Anyway this is the way to get the terms of a custom taxonomy and each product attribute is a custom taxonomy.

Comment: Ok, found the problem. I think we should turn show empty to false to show all the terms. Any idea how to fix (that a stupid question - of course you know) :)
Thx for the help

Comment: oops - 28 seconds to late :)